# Creating an Entity Framework Core Value Converter: The property 'Remark' is of type 'string' which is not supported by the current database provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I've got my internal domain, which has a `string` property remark. In my database, I want to store an empty `string` as `NULL` and when I load an `NULL` from the db, I want this to be an empty `string`.

I thought I'd create a `ValueConverter` and register it and that would be it.

```
public class StringEmptyToNullConverter : ValueConverter<string, string>
{
    public StringEmptyToNullConverter() : base(ToDatabaseValue, ToDomainValue) {}

    private static readonly Expression<Func<string, string>> ToDatabaseValue =
        domainValue => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domainValue) ? null : domainValue;

    private static readonly Expression<Func<string, string>> ToDomainValue = databaseValue =>
        databaseValue ?? string.Empty;
}
```

In my context configuration, I register this as either `builder.Property(x => x.Remark).HasConversion(new StringEmptyToNullConverter());`, which still stores an empty `string` in the database or gives me back an `NULL` value. Basically, this gets ignored.

Or I register it as `builder.Property(x => x.Opmerking).HasConversion<StringEmptyToNullConverter>();`, which throws an error:

> The property 'Remark' is of type 'string' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Does anybody know why what I'm doing wrong in my converter?

Addition: when I put a breakpoint in the lambda statements, the breakpoint is never hit.

I also tried registering the lambdas direcly: `...HasConversion(domainValue => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domainValue) ? null : domainValue, databaseValue => databaseValue ?? string.Empty);` which is the same outcome as the first registration.

Comment: That's an **awful** idea. An empty string is most definitely **NOT** null. It has a very specific value, the empty string. In both SQL and .NET these two are completely different. In SQL you can't search for nulls by value (you can do so for empty strings) so converting empty strings to NULLs will break queries. You'll have to write `.Where(p=>p.ThatField == null)` instead of `.Where(=>p.ThatField = "")`

Comment: The remark field is not meant as a searchable field. The reason I need to do this is to keep the domain correct and the architect wants to keep the db as small as possible (there are already a lot of huge db's), so empty strings should not be persisted to the db.

Comment: The architect should know that this is a bad idea and the savings negligible. If you really care about space, use table compression. That's available in all supported SQL Server versions and editions, even Express and LocalDB. You'll end improving performance because IO will be reduced. If you have large tables used for reporting, a columstore clustered index will reduce storage (and improve performance) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that prevent this from working.  Given:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(c => c.Name)
            .HasConversion(
                ev => ev==""?null:ev, 
                dv => dv==null?"":dv
                );
```

First, the value conversion on queries doesn't transform the predicate to `is null`, it simply generates `= null` which in standard SQL never matches any rows as `null = null` evaluates to `unknown`, eg

a query like this:

```
var q2 = from cust in db.Customers
        where cust.Name == ""
        select cust;
```

translates to

```
  SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Name]
  FROM [Customers] AS [c]
  WHERE [c].[Name] = NULL
```

Second, the value coverter can't convert null in the database to "" in .NET:

> Also, value converters do not generally allow the conversion of null
> to some other value. This is because the same value converter can be
> used for both nullable and non-nullable types, which is very useful
> for PK/FK combinations where the FK is often nullable and the PK is
> not. We will discuss whether or not to add support for converting
> nulls.

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13850

This currently simply won't work.  So don't want to mix empty string and null (and you don't), and if you want consistency between the entities and the database, your only choice is to use null in both places.

Comment: The remark field is not meant as a searchable field. The reason I need to do this is to keep the domain correct and the architect wants to keep the db as small as possible (there are already a lot of huge db's), so empty strings should not be persisted to the db.
What I did notice is that it does put an `null` value in the db, but puts that `null` into my property. It does not seem to translate the db `null` into empty `string`. I've put breakpoints into the code and they are not hit. Could it be that the property has a backing field and is not an autoproperty?

Comment: Ah, value conversions currently don't allow the conversion of `null` to something else.  The converter simply doesn't run for null values.

Comment: If you put that in a solution (or add it to this one), I'll mark it as solved. 

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: For those looking for an answer. I've made a property with a backing field like this: `public string Remark { get => _remark ?? string.Empty; set => _remark = value?.Trim() }`.

Comment: Since "remark field is not meant as a searchable field" that's a fine solution.